# ios casting objc pointer to struct cgcolorref

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers, automatic-ref-counting, cgcolor

I have `ARC` enabled and I'm trying to do:

```
CGColorRef outerColor = (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

My attempted cast results in the error:

```
Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'CGColorRef' (aka 'struct CGColor *') is disallowed with ARC
```

I've tried a number of things, but I don't know how to complete this cast.

Comment: cant you just remove (id) cast ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bridge the cast so ARC can understand what you are doing and how to react to it. Check the accepted answer of this question out: [ARC and bridged cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036350/arc-and-bridged-cast)

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP)*.

I am adding `outerColor` to an array so I did this:

```
CAGradientLayer *maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

CGColorRef outerColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
CGColorRef innerColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;

maskLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)outerColor, 
                    (__bridge id)innerColor, (__bridge id)innerColor, (__bridge id)outerColor, nil];
```