# Passing arguments with AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, audio

I'm trying to pass a `UILabel` with `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion` but i'm not able to manipulate the value within the `completionCallback` method. I'm using ARC and Xcode suggested adding `(_bridge void*)`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
-(void) playWordSound:(UILabel *)label
{
    NSString *path;
    SystemSoundID soundId;
    switch (label.tag)
    {
        case 1:
            ..........
            break;
    }
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID( (CFURLRef)objc_unretainedPointer( url), &soundId);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId);
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (soundId, NULL, NULL, 
                                           completionCallback,
                                           (__bridge void*) label);
}


static void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* data) {
    NSLog(@"completion Callback");
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (mySSID);
    //the below line is not working
    //label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the completion handler the label is stored in `data`. You need to `__bridge` it back to use it.

```
static void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void* data) {
    NSLog(@"completion Callback");
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (mySSID);
    UILabel *label = (__bridge UILabel*)data;
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks, it's working for me now. Could you briefly explain to a noob the idea behind bridging and what exactly it does?

Comment: It was introduced in ARC to handle ref-counting when storing to a generic type like `void*`. See [ARC and bridged cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036350/arc-and-bridged-cast)

Comment: Joe, could you tell me how to call another method from within the `completionCallback` method. After i change the text color i've tried calling another method with `[self anotherMethod]`, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Start up another question and just post a link here. Make sure you check to see if it has been answered already.