# Audiostreamer iOS class - ARC error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, audio-streaming, audiostreamer

I'm trying to implement Matt Gallagher's [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) class and I'm getting 20+ errors on `Audiostream.m` file that are basically reading:

`Cast of C pointer type 'void *' to Objective-C pointer type 'AudioStreamer *' requires a bridged cast`

I'm new to iOS. I know what ARC is, but what does this error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the error suggests you need a [bridged cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036350/arc-and-bridged-cast). Please read that question for the differences between the available bridged casts. And if you have time watch WWDC 2011 session 323.

---

You probably just need something like this:

```
AudioSessionInitialize (
    NULL,                          // 'NULL' to use the default (main) run loop
    NULL,                          // 'NULL' to use the default run loop mode
    MyAudioSessionInterruptionListener,  // a reference to your interruption callback
    (__bridge void *)(self)                       // data to pass to your interruption listener callback
);
```