# bridged cast: __bridge_transfer vs __bridge with synthesized setter

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC, and have confusion while using `__bridge_transfer`. I have a property `userName` as following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userName;
...
@synthesize userName = _userName;
...
```

CASE **1**:

```
NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
self.userName = name;
```

CASE **2**:

```
self.userName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
```

where `person` is of type `ABRecordRef`.

In CASE **1**, ARC would release local variable name (as per my understanding, correct me if I am wrong), however what would happen in CASE **2** ? Should I use `__bridge` in CASE **2** OR CASE **2** should not be used at all ? in CASE **2** with `__bridge_transfer` or `__bridge`, how to balance the reference count ?

in CASE **2**, with `__bridge_transfer`, will ARC release the object (the object, which is being passed as an argument to the setter `(void)setUserName:(NSString *)userName`)?

Answer (score 22):

When you call `ABRecordCopyCompositeName()`, *someone* must release the returned object at some point.  Using `__bridge_transfer` ensures that ARC will release the object for you.  Without `__bridge_transfer`, you must release the returned object manually.  Those are the only two options.

Therefore, you must use `__bridge_transfer` in both cases.

A nice exercise is to induce a leak by using `__bridge` instead of `__bridge_transfer`, then use Xcode and Instruments to try and find the leak.  Does the compiler pick up the leak?  Does static analysis (Project -> Analyze) pick up the leak?  Does Instruments pick up the leak?  If so, you'll then know how to check whether `__bridge_transfer` solves the problem.

Comment: I understand, what you have written. But in CASE **2**, with `__bridge_transfer`, would ARC release the object (the object, which is being passed as an argument to the setter `(void)setUserName:(NSString *)userName`)too ?

Comment: @Kailash You can expect Case 2 to work no differently than, say, `self.userName = [someString copy];`.  When you use __bridge_transfer, ARC will release the object regardless of whether it is assigned to a temporary variable.  I recommend using Instruments to verify this.

Comment: I already tried `__bridge` in CASE **2** before posting the question. Both _Static Analyzer_ and _Instruments_ confirm this as a leak. However, I needed to know how the system works. Your above comment is what I needed to clarify. You asked me to verify it using _Instruments_, are not you sure about what you said or you just asked to make me understand ?

Answer (score 4):

Case 1 and case 2 are equivalent.  Think of it like this:

Case 1:

```
-(void)func {
  NSString *name = someObject;  // Retain, so +1 on the reference count
  self.userName = name;         // Retain, so +1 on the reference count
  // End of function, name is going out of scope,
  // so release name, so -1 on the reference count.
  // Total change to the reference count: +1 for self.userName.
}
```

Case 2:

```
-(void)func {
  self.userName = someObject;   // Retain, so +1 on the reference count
  // End of function.
  // Total change to the reference count: +1 for self.userName.
}
```

So they work out the same.  Note that the compiler is allowed to cancel out a retain and release pair, if it is safe to do so.  In a simple case like this it would certainly elide them.  Thinking about it with all the +1 and -1 changes to the reference count is just to make it clearer.

To answer the bit about __bridge versus __bridge_transfer: you have called `ABRecordCopyCompositeName`, which returns a reference to an unmanaged object (a `CFStringRef`).  The `Copy` in the function name tells you that this object is now owned by you, and you need to release it eventually.

You can either do this by calling `CFRelease`, or you can ask ARC to do it for you.  `__bridge` tells ARC that it is not allowed to take ownership (in other words, you want to release the object manually, or it isn't owned by you).  `__bridge_transfer` tells ARC that it should take ownership and release the object at the end of the full expression (in other words, you are asking ARC to do the release for you).

With `__bridge_transfer`:

```
self.userName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);  // +1 inside ABRecordCopyCompositeName, +1 for self.userName, -1 at the end, because of the __bridge_transfer.
// self.userName now is the only strong reference.  Good.
```

With `__bridge`:

```
CFStringRef userName = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);  // +1 inside ABRecordCopyCompositeName.
self.userName = (__bridge NSString *)userName;             // +1 for self.userName, ARC does nothing because of the __bridge.
CFRelease(userName);                                       // -1.
// self.userName now is the only strong reference.  Good.
```

With `__bridge` and a memory leak:

```
self.userName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);  // +1 inside ABRecordCopyCompositeName, +1 for self.userName, ARC does nothing because of the __bridge.
// self.userName now is one strong reference, but reference count is 2.
// Memory leak.
```

Answer (score 1):

Precisely because this is confusing, I recommend that you use `CFBridgingRelease()` and `CFBridgingRetain()` rather than casts with `__bridge_transfer` and `__bridge_retained`, respectively. Then, the only "unusual" cast you need to remember is `__bridge`, which does nothing with ownership.

I find it easier to remember because, with something like `ABRecordCopyCompositeName()` which leaves you with the responsibility to `CFRelease()` the returned object, you can use `CFBridgingRelease()` to discharge that responsibility and the analogy is obvious.

Similarly, you'd only use `CFBridgingRetain()` in a context where you would use `CFRetain()` if the object pointer were already a Core Foundation type.

So, your code could be:

```
NSString *name = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person));
self.userName = name;
```

Or:

```
self.userName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person));
```

In both cases, the `CFBridgingRelease()` balances the `Copy` in the function name that implies that you have a responsibility to release the object. After that, it's all somebody else's responsibility. ARC manages the `name` variable. The implementer of the setter for the `userName` property manages that. (It happens to be ARC in this case, too, but that's irrelevant.)