# Will this code leak if I remove CFRelease?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge  CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
    NSRange  rangeHighlight = NSMakeRange(range.location, substringToHighlight.length);
    if (font) {
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge  id)font range:rangeHighlight];
        CFRelease(font); //Is this still necessary?
    }
```

I copy and paste this code from https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

```
  CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
  if (font) {
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(id)font range:boldRange];
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:@"TTTStrikeOutAttribute" value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] range:strikeRange];
    CFRelease(font);
  }
```

When I do that I got an error saying that I got to use the keyword __bridge. What is it? I put it and compile error stop. But then I wonder if I still need to use CFRelease(font)

In addition

1. What is CF in CFRelease?
2. What is __bridge?
3. Should I do CFRelease(font) after using __bridge?
4. Where can I learn more about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you still need to use CFRelease(font).

You are still the one creating the *font* so you need to release it as well. The __bridge part is related to how the font *name* is retained or not.

1. CF is short for Core Foundation, the C level API that Foundation is built upon. CFRelease is how you release a Core Foundation object.
2. __bridge tells ARC how it should retain or not retain an objects when translating it to a Core Foundation object. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7036350/608157) explains the different __bridge types.
3. You should still release (explained above).
4. Search for "Core Foundation". The [Design Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/CFDesignConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000122i) explains the general design.

Answer (score 2):

1. CF stands for "Core Foundation". A CTFontRef is a Core Foundation type so you can release it with CFRelease().
2. `__bridge` is a keyword used when casting from a retainable type to a non-retainable type (or vice versa) to tell the compiler there should be no change of ownership happening.
3. Yes, because `__bridge` does not change who the owner is.
4. [This documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) is fairly comprehensive.

Comment: I thought both CFStringRef and NSString * is retainable except that ARC automatically take care of the retain thingy? So CTFontCreateWithName increase retain count by 1 am I correct?

Comment: CFStringRef *are* retainable per se, but not in the sense that ARC is concerned with. ARC considers a type "retainable" if it is a pointer to an Objective-C object (as opposed to a pointer to a `float` or any other kind of struct, etc). CFStringRef are not Objective-C objects so for the sake of ARC, they are non-retainable. There are functions `CFBridgingRelease` and `CFBridgingRetain` that handle the transfer of ownership. In your case, I think you can get rid of the `__bridge` **and** the `CFRelease()` if you replace the cast with `CFBridgingRelease(font)`.

Comment: I did CFBridgingRelease(CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge  CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL)) and it doesn't work.