# Determining the instance of a class given one of its variables

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

Hi guys I am currently stuck working on an app here. The problem is that I have a class that creates a number of instances each made up of a CCPhysicsSprite and a b2body. During collision with any other object from any other class, that particular instance should disappear. Now I have created a contact listener that determines contact and the problem is that I need to get access to the particular instance in order to destroy it. At best, I am able to get access to its CCPhysicsSprite and its tag but can't really get the particular instance of the class. I hope someone helps me out there.

Comment: Show some code. Usually, the box2d body's userData field has a pointer to the CCPhysicsSprite instance. So if you can access the CCPhysicsSprite object, then that's the instance you're looking for. Unless you're looking for a third class not mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the instance as a UserData in to the box2d body. When the collision happens you can retrieve the instance by casting back the user data void pointer in to its correct type and deal with it accordingly.

```
// C++ example
void SomeClass::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    b2Body* bA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
    b2Body* bB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
    b2MetaData* bAMeta = (b2MetaData*)bA->GetUserData();
    b2MetaData* bBMeta = (b2MetaData*)bB->GetUserData();

    delete bAMeta;
    delete bBMeta;
}
```

If the instance is a Objective-C instance you will probably have to use __bridge casting.
More info on how to use it you can find here. [SO - ARC and bridged cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261584/1464294)

Remember that removing of the box2d body it self has to be done outside the world step, so its better if you would just mark the body for removal in some way (a flag in it or maybe add it to a list called toBeRemoved) and after the step has ended you can iterate over the container removing the box2d bodies.