# Set border for UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, cgcolor

I am trying to keep border for UIButton.If i use the following code it's working.

**Case:1**

```
[[_myButton layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[[_myButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
```

But before when i wrote:

```
self.baseTypeButton.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
self.myButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

XCode proposed me to do

[image]

Now my code changed,but i failed to set border in this case:

**Case:2**

```
_myButton.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
_myButton.layer.borderColor=(__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor lightGrayColor]);
```

I am not using **Auto-layout**. Can anybody explain what is the difference between case-1 and case-2. Why case-2 wont work.

Comment: did you add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework ?

Comment: @ivarun:QuartzCore framework is already added in my project

Comment: UIColor is not CGColor. You can't bridge it. You might use this to save yor time https://github.com/AlexHsieh/ButtonAppearance

Comment: @AlexHsieh: really thankyou for your support. in your github link "AHButton.h" file is missing.

Comment: @uday.m , there are 2 ways to use it. 1. use cocoapod or 2. you can just copy file from here https://github.com/AlexHsieh/ButtonAppearance/tree/master/Pod/Classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

layer.borderColor must be CGColor, so code below will work.

```
_myButton.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
_myButton.layer.borderColor=[ UIColor lightGrayColor ].CGColor;
```

Your code

```
   [UIColor lightGrayColor]
```

returns a UIColor instance, not a CGColor instance. And UIColor can't bridge to CGColor, so your cast

```
(__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)
```

returns unexpected result.

You can see strange result using this code

```
NSLog( @"%@", (__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor lightGrayColor]) );
```

returning below. ( Xcode 7.3 )

```
2016-04-06 15:30:51.415 36442877[8570:2643221] UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0.666667 1
```

If you give borderColor CGColor instance directory, you don't need casting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ARC in your project than,

```
_myButton.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
_myButton.layer.borderColor=(__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable)([UIColor lightGrayColor]);
```

Will not work, because `__bridge CGColorRef _Nullable` will autorelease reference.the moment CFRelease() is called the object is gone and points to nothing.

And

```
[[_myButton layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[[_myButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
```

will work as expected.

For more information check:

[ARC and bridged cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036350/arc-and-bridged-cast)

Comment: Search for ARC on web, i am not talking about Xib or auto-autolayout@uday.m

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
_myButton.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
_myButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
```